# write list of xts objects to excel

Tags: r, list, time-series, xts, zoo

I have a list of 337 XTS objects which looks like this:

```
> head(blowup.instances)
$`AERI.US.Equity`
           AERI.US.Equity
2015-04-24     -0.6363379

$SRPT.US.Equity
           SRPT.US.Equity
2013-11-12     -0.6400985
2016-01-15     -0.5485299

$PTCT.US.Equity
           PTCT.US.Equity
2016-02-23      -0.616419
```

When I try to write them to a csv, it does not work:

```
> write.csv(blowup.instances, "blowupInstances.csv")
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 9, 5, 6, 18, 37, 8, 10, 78, 25, 11, 12, 20, 59, 17, 19, 27, 29, 16, 14, 31, 15, 51, 28, 54
```

Now I know why this doesn't work, but I want to know a solution to this other than writing out a large data frame full of `NA` values that I would have to remove in Excel. Any ideas?

Comment: You can try `row.names = FALSE` argument in the `write.csv()` function for that error. However, you can open up what you mean by removing NA values and a reproducible example will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to read your list of xts objects into Excel, you probably need to convert it to a flat file.  The code below transforms each `xts` object into a data frame with each row containing the `xts` object name, and its dates and values.  The `map_dfr` function from the `purrr` package in `tidyverse` is used to loop over the `xts` objects in the list and combine the results into a single data frame.

```
library(xts) 
 library(tidyverse)
#
#  combine list of xts objects into a single data frame with equity names and dates
# 

  df_out <- map_dfr(blowup.instances, function(y) data_frame(Name = names(y), Date = index(y), value=as.vector(coredata(y))) )
#
#   write as csv flat file
#
  write.csv(df_out, file="blowupInstances.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

The data frame written to the file is

```
df_out
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  Name           Date       value
  <chr>          <date>     <dbl>
1 AERI.US.Equity 2018-06-27 -0.5 
2 SRPT.US.Equity 2018-06-26 -0.64
3 SRPT.US.Equity 2018-06-27 -0.55
4 PTCT.US.Equity 2018-06-20 -0.7
```

where the data a simple example set I made.

Comment: I forgot to check this, and ended up doing something pretty similar using a for loop, but your version is much cleaner! Thank you, and appreciate the response.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `blowup.instances` is a list.  Don't write the list to file.

Assuming this is the case, you can do either of these:

```
syms <- names(blowup.instances)

lapply(syms, FUN = function(sym) {
  write.zoo(x = blowup.instances[[sym]], file = paste0(sym, "-data.csv"))
})
```

Alternatively:

```
res <- do.call(cbind, blowup.instances)
write.zoo(res, file = "crosssecdata.csv")
```

I recommend the first approach. Put the data for each symbol in a separate file.

Comment: 1st approach isn't quite what I was looking for and the second one sends out a ton of NA values, which I could deal with in excel, but would be a bit of a pain. The guy above had a very nice solution.